# Regular Expression to determine if phone number is 'local', 'national', 'mobile', 'premium', etc

Tags: php, regex, bash, preg-match, grep

I'm knocking up a simple PHP form to show telephone call usage on our asterisk system. All call information is being recorded in a database.

I'm familiar with regular expressions and PHP (to a degree), but have never attempted to combine the two before.

Parsing the data, I want to identify the outgoing call type, so that we can bill our customer at the correct rate. I'm splitting the outgoing calls into a number of classes, for example, 'local', 'national', 'mobile', 'premium', 'international' and 'internal', however my attempts to match the first class (i.e. 'local') have failed.

Local calls will always have a `9` prefix, which is optionally followed by the local area code (`01234` in this example). This is then followed by the local number (`567890` in this example). Note that the local number can't start with a zero.

So the numbers I'm trying to match for the above examples are `901234567890` or `9567890`.

I would normally use a regex such as `^9(01234)?[1-9][0-9]+`, and testing this from a bash shell, I get the expected results

```
$ echo 091234567890 | egrep -e '^9(01234)?[1-9][0-9]+'
901234567890
$ echo 9567890 | egrep -e '^9(01234)?[1-9][0-9]+'
9567890
$ echo 908001234567 | egrep -e '^9(01234)?[1-9][0-9]+'
$ echo 901987654321 | egrep -e '^9(01234)?[1-9][0-9]+'
$ echo 907890123456 | egrep -e '^9(01234)?[1-9][0-9]+'
```

so attempting to translate this to work in PHP, I've come up with the following:

```
$class='Unknown';
if (preg_match('/^9(01234)?[1-9][0-9]+/', $dest))
  $class='Local Call';
// More regex matches to follow for other classes
```

Now, when I throw the following list of numbers at the above

```
901234567890
9567890
908001234567
901987654321
907890123456
```

every one of the numbers appears to match the regex. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran the test on all your numbers and it worked:

```
$nums = array('901234567890', '9567890'
   , '908001234567', '901987654321', '907890123456');
foreach ($nums as $num) {
   if (preg_match('/^9(01234)?[1-9][0-9]+/', $num)) {
      echo "$num passes\n";
   }
   else {
      echo "$num fails\n";
   }
}
```

---

```
901234567890 passes
9567890 passes
908001234567 fails
901987654321 fails
907890123456 fails
```

In your code, all that passing does is set a variable, so maybe you need to check that it's being set..

In addition to that, I will say that checking phone numbers against a regex is a doomed endeavor.  That's going a bit far, but it is very difficult.  The phone number parsing class at my job is over 1400 lines long and still doesn't work properly in all cases.

Comment: I can't believe what I've done! The code i pasted into SO was a simplified version. In my real code, I wasn't correctly clearing $class at each pass, so when no match was found, it used the previous match value of $class. I'd managed to convince myself that it was the regex. Accepting your answer, as it was your suggestion to check the variable was being set that prompted me to spot the error.

Answer (score 3):

Works as expected for me. Is `$dest` being set correctly?

---

*My test*

```
$nums = array(
    901234567890,
    9567890,
    908001234567,
    901987654321,
    907890123456,
);

foreach ($nums as $num) {
    if (preg_match('/^9(01234)?[1-9][0-9]+/', $num)) {
        echo "$num matches\n";
    }
}
```

*Results*

```
901234567890 matches
9567890 matches
```

Comment: Works as expected for me too.

Answer (score 2):

Are you throwing all the numbers at the code as **a single string**? Because that's not at all the same as sending them one by one. If one of the lines match the regex the whole test succeeds. In other words, it's equivalent to this:

```
echo '901234567890
9567890
908001234567
901987654321
907890123456' | egrep -e '^9(01234)?[1-9][0-9]+'
```

Use [Wiseguy's method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831393/php-regular-expression-not-working/5831716#5831716).

Answer (score 1):

```
$n[] = 901234567890;
$n[] = 9567890;
$n[] = 908001234567;
$n[] = 901987654321;
$n[] = 907890123456;
$n[] = 901;

foreach( $n as $t){

if (preg_match('/^9(01234)?[1-9][0-9]+/', $t))
  echo 'Local Call' . PHP_EOL ;

}
```

That gives me two local calls?